# How do I use the Claw with Overlord?

Tags: diep.io

I have seen several players able to move their drones away from them, out of their FOV, and then pull another player in by bringing the drones back and surround them on both sides.

How can I do this as an Overlord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should start as an Overlord with a bullet build. Other Overlords won't make a dent in other players using their drones.

Enable **Auto Fire** using <kbd>E</kbd> or hold down your mouse button. This will make the drones follow your mouse.

You can now place your drones in the direction you want to claw. Move your mouse into your tank and hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> or your secondary mouse button. This will repel the drones and allow them to get behind the tank.

Once you think the drones have gotten around your enemy, put your mouse closest to where you think your enemy is and stop repelling. They will be surrounded by multiple drones in all directions.

You must account for the opponent's movement as well:

> To account for the momentum of the most likely moving tank when the claw is closing put your mouse just behind them so your drones are behind then instead of in front.

<sup>— from `BADLAMP<(❂)>[LAMPLORD]#6305` on [the Diep Colony Discord server](https://discord.gg/sbKzqfM)</sup>

### Image Guides

Alternatively, you can follow this image guide:

[image: Claw image guide]

### Video Examples

You can also watch the gameplay of a few fights where the Overlord clawed the opponent several times to replicate the behavior:

- [Overlord vs. Fighter](https://streamable.com/hpr56)
- [Overlord vs. Penta Shot #1](https://streamable.com/ehdyc)
- [Overlord vs. Penta Shot #2](https://streamable.com/4emgc)
- [Overlord vs. Penta Shot #3](https://streamable.com/ofur2)
- [Overlord vs. Penta Shot #4](https://streamable.com/rjrjr)
- [Overlord vs. Penta Shot #5](https://streamable.com/8z35y)

Comment: I couldn't find the Penta Shot video.  I tried to look for it.  Did it exist or was there only one video?

Comment: @Nelson Both existed equally and were made by the same player.

Answer (score 0):

so basically all you do is pint your mouse to the opposite direction you want your drones to go. Then as they are moving there hold shift or right click. "Repelling" will make your drones go to the opposite direction that the mouse is at. So then your drones are spreading around your target. you then stop holding shift and swallow the target with your drones. easy.